# Using greasemonkey script to automate flash application

Tags: javascript, flash, testing, selenium, greasemonkey

Is there way to simulate click on a flash application using Greasemonkey script?

I need to test a flash app with lot of permutations and combinations. Traditional approach of using `ExternalInterface` wont work because it is too cumbersome to add the callback.

Comment: Do you have access to flash source?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript(Greasemonkey) can execute public methods like SetVariable and GetVariable

Here's an example of usage: [ActionScript Console: Hack Flash Games](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/32886)

If there is a public method to simulate click, then there is a way to simulate click.

Comment: Is there any "Hello World" to get started? I couldn't figure out how this works? Any Help appreciated.